# Remove Duplicate Query

Tags: mysql, sql

The below query gives me 1716,

```
select distinct ce_email from comm_list where clp_no = 585
```

When I add a c_no to the query the results go up by one to 1717. Is there a way to only show the MAX(c_no) and ce_email so I don't have duplicate ce_emails? I need all the emails but I can't have duplicates and I need to associate them with a c_no.

Comment: `GROUP BY` is your friend.

Comment: `select distinct` applies to the entire row of fields you're selecting. it's not `select distinct(foo), bar`, it's `select distinct(foo,bar)`, essentially. you'd need to use `selecct maxx(ce_no), ce_email ... group by ce_email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Group By` like this:

```
SELECT ce_email,max(c_no)
FROM comm_list
WHERE clp_no = 585
GROUP BY ce_email;
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3538/1/0)